# TWO NIC AND SQUID

Tags: squid

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system to use as a server in my office having 50 employees. I have 2 LAN cards in my system:

```
One for input from a BSNL router (192.168.1.250) to my Ubuntu server (192.168.1.1.)
Another one from the server (192.168.1.1) to a switch which connects all the employees through squid from that switch via LAN cables.
```

How can I configure both LAN cards and squid?